Entropy of the alignment of nails in a box
In this video, someone shakes a box of nails and the nails seem to spontaneously align. According to the explanation in the original tweet, this is because the nails have more possible configurations in an aligned state and therefore more entropy:

As I see it the potential energy of the nails convert to kinetic energy so it transfers energy all through the box the entropy of the system is increased.

However, if the box was tipped over, the nails would end up in an unaligned state. According to the explanation above, this state should have lower entropy than the previous state, even though we added only a small amount of energy to tip the box.
Can anyone explain?

It's really unclear what is this "little energy" thing you are talking about. Please give at least a link to the video you are referring to.

Anyway, nails are athermal systems. A strong shaking of the box allows the system to explore the "configuration space" and possible reach a nematic state that is more favorable in term of entropy/number of configurations. If you don't shake the system strongly, you will not explore the configuration space and hence, will stay in your initial state. You can look at "jamming", "random close packing", and "glass transition in undercool liquids"

Very easy to fake this by playing a video backwards.

@Syrocco There isn't a video of people tipping over the box. Just of people shaking the box till the nails align.

Is the fact that the system athermal because we cannot define the temperature as the thermodynamic beta or just cause we don't want to see an spotaneous decrease of tempertaure?

Could you provide a link/reference for the supposed explanation mentioned in your question?

@David_h https://x.com/gunsnrosesgirl3/status/1632067559070793729

There is no spontaneous alignment. Also the shaking is not done randomly. There is a clear strategy that allows for alignment with less time/energy than random shaking.
A rectangular box causes preferential alignment of the nails along the walls of the container. Any nail not parallel to a wall will become parallel if the direction of shaking is perpendicular to the wall. In the videos, it's clear that the shaking is always done in a direction that is perpendicular to either the side or front/back walls. First is a side to side motion to line up the nails parallel to each other. Then front to back shaking to separate the aligned into rows.
If the container was spherical in shape, there would be less preferential alignment due to shaking. It would require shaking for a substantially longer time before an aligned state is reached.

The aligned state has lower entropy, not higher entropy. It is actually energetically favored, not entropically favored.
There is a reasonably good analogy between the behavior of the nails and phase transitions, as follows:

If the box is shaken very violently (high temperature), the nails fly around all in three dimensions and we have the most entropically favored (but least energetically favored) solution, analogous to a gas.

If the shaking is less violent (moderate temperature), all or most of the nails remain at the bottom of the box (thus achieving a lower-energy state), but they are randomly oriented and move around freely, analogous to a liquid. Compared to the gas, this is energetically favored, because the nails sit lower in the box, but entropically disfavored, because the nails can no longer occupy many of their possible posistional state.

If the "liquid" state is cooled slowly enough, it may freeze into a crystalline solid with the nails aligned. This is even more energetically favored, because the aligned nails pack better and fit lower in the box. However, there are even fewer possible arrangements of the nails, since their rotation is now constrained, and thus the entropy is lowered even further. Trying to grow a single large crystal is a delicate process, both for real materials and for nails. In the video I watched, it appeared that the temperature was periodically increased and decreased in an attempt to get the nails to align. A similar process, annealing, is often used for real materials.

If the "liquid" state is cooled fast, the nails freeze into an amorphous solid or glass, as they do not have enough time to reach their energetically optimal state. This happens if you tip the box over.


